# Raabe-Duhamel test for $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{a^nn!}{n^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to prove the convergence/divergence of this summation using *Raabe-Duhamel test*.
I reached to this point after writing up $\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}$:

$$\frac{(n+1)^n(n+1)}{an^n}$$

I don't know how to continue it.
$a\ge0$.

Comment: **HINT** $\dfrac{(n+1)^n}{n^n}=(1+1/n)^n\to e$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ratio $a_n/a_{n+1}$ is the OP is not quite correct.  Instead, note that we have for $a\ne0$

$$\begin{align}
\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}&=\frac{a^nn!/n^n}{a^{n+1}(n+1)!/(n+1)^{n+1}}\\\\
&=\frac1a\,\,\frac{n!}{(n+1)!}\,\,\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{n^n}\\\\
&=\frac1a\,\,\frac1{n+1}\,\,\frac{(n+1)(n+1)^n}{n^n}\\\\
&=\frac1a\,\,\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^n}\\\\
&=\frac1a \left(1+\frac1n\right)^n
\end{align}$$

And inasmuch as $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=e$, we find that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=\frac ea$$

and the ratio test reveals that the series converges for $a<e$ and diverges for $a>e$.

But the ratio test is inconclusive for $a=e$.  For $a=e$ the Raabe-Duhamel test reveals

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(n\left(\frac1e \left(1+\frac1n\right)^n-1\right) \right)=-\frac12$$

and we can conclude that the series diverges for $a\ge e$ and converges for $a<e$.

Comment: Thank you, I really made a rookie mistake... Also, sorry if I'm wrong (and the lack of formatting language for the equation), but isn't the Raabe-Duhamel test 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty }n*(\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}-1)$$
?

Shouldn't I place in this equation the penultimate line you wrote?

Comment: I understand your solution, and thank you for it - my requirement was to use Raabe-Duhamel, don't know why, when it can be resolved without it...

Comment: For $a>e$, the R-D test yields $-\infty$, for $a<e$, it yields $\infty$, and for $a=e$, the result is $-1/2$.

Comment: I've edited to show the utility of the R-D test over the ratio test.  Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can

Comment: Thank you, I understood it very well the second time!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  Pleased to hear you have it.